# Spring from a GWT

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, gwt

I have the next problem. I did simple project using Spring and Hibernate. Here is the structure of my project: (oh, I cant attach images).

Structure:

1. module "service" - the whole business logic;
2. module "war" - generates war file with client side part.

In a module war I have an .jsp page that generates table with data from database. There are also a few servlets. In my .jsp page I used Spring to get my service with movies.

```
ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
                MovieService bean = (MovieService) context.getBean("movieService");
                List<Movie> movieList = bean.getAllMovies();
```

Now, I need to use GWT here. How can I use Spring in GWT app? I just add new module with GWT framework, and in entry class I can not use WebAppContext...

What should I use? However, I can directly use my service class, but it is not cool :) I want to use it like in .jsp page.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have 3 options:

1. Use [spring4gwt](https://code.google.com/p/spring4gwt/) (maybe project is dead)
2. Use your controller as RESTful service (possibly it's not what you want)
3. Use spring like in [this](http://www.springbyexample.org/static/1.1/html/simple-gwt-spring-webapp-gwt.html) example

Also [here](https://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/gwt-rpc-integration-with-spring/) you can find example of self-made analogue of spring4gwt, maye it works too